# Add delay to a for-loop without using Thread.sleep -- Nevermind it's a bad idea

Tags: java, split

I have this code which takes in a `String`...

```
//Takes in string from whatever it is, in this case a JOptionPane
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input string");
//if there is a string 
if (!(input == null)) {
    //splits the string into smaller strings of 100 characters for loop that prints the strings  
    int count = input.length() / 100 + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println(input.substring(i * 100, (i + 1) * 100 >= input.length() ? input.length() : (i + 1) * 100));
    }
}
```

..and I want to add a delay to the string so that it doesn't all print the strings in succession at once but instead prints one string every second without using a `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could do this?

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep()` for that.

Comment: "without using a thread.sleep"... why? thread.sleep is the way this is done, what is your reason for not wanting to use the normal and accepted method?

Comment: You could spin in a while loop tracking the passing System.currentTimeMillis(), but sleep is really the best solution.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with the question here.  The constraint is unorthodox but I don't see a problem with the question as posed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) a task using ScheduledExecutorService to print the next characters with an initial delay. Then reschedule with the next characters to print until you finish. ScheduledExecutorService runs on a different thread so if you want to wait until all the String is printed you will have to use something like a CompletableFuture to indicate when all is done. Also make sure the thread has stopped when the printing is complete so it wont run indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is simply not intuitive* *without* the use of `Thread.sleep`, because that is far and away the simplest approach to adding a delay in your code.

To rephrase it:  any solution you'd want to come up with that avoids the direct `Thread.sleep` would involve adding the strings to some buffer or waiting area, polling that buffer every second, and printing it out to string, until the buffer is depleted.  Effectively this is accomplished with worker threads and queues, but if the intent is to only ever print the strings out, the simplest effect would be to use `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

<sup>*: I say "intuitive" since there may be a way to do it, but any alternative workarounds would likely use `Thread.sleep` with several layers of indirection.</sup>